# How to dualize norm-constrained optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, duality-theorems

Consider the following optimization problem:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}}{\text{min}}
& & c^{T}x \\
& \text{s.t.}
& & ||x-\hat{x}||_{q} \leq \delta,\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $q$ could be 1, 2 or "inf".

Could anybody give some suggestions on how to dualize the norm-constrained problem like this?
Thanks!